# Is it possible to skip Tutorial Island?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I played this game long time ago, but I still remember how to play the basics that we learn in Tutorial Island.

I created a new character and it went right away to Tutorial Island. Is there any way to skip Tutorial Island?

Comment: In certain game modes you can, such as Deadman mode tournaments and seasons, and King of the Skill.  In those game modes, the NPC Skippy is next to the door of the first building you spawn in on the island.  You can talk to him to have him teleport you off the island.  You will be given all of the equipment you would normally obtain from going through the entire tutorial as well. I believe that Skippy is not present on tutorial island for the regular game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, according to [this wiki page](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Tutorial_Island) all new characters are required to complete Tutorial Island.

> Every new RuneScape character starts out on the Tutorial Island.

Tutorial Island was not removed until 2008 (permanently in 2012), which is later than the version Old School Runescape is using from 2007.

At one point, there was a way to skip this, as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape/comments/33v7vv/tutorial_island_skip/), but it was later removed due to the fact that it was mainly being used by bots to bypass the tutorial segment and get right into the game.